# Run apps on device after update to Xcode4

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm a **newbie** iOs developer and my company just purchased the developer license from apple.
After the purchase, I downloaded xcode and started developing, working my way to deploy my apps on our iPad, obtaining the provisioning file etc. 
Yesterday I decided to **upgrade to Xcode4** to the new version and since the upgrade i can't deploy the apps I'm working on any longer.
I've searched for answers on google, but I haven't found anything helpful.

Thanks anyway.

Fat Chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi
Go to the project info, change the target version to your ios version that is installed on the device itself and not to the latest.
Thanks